# How do you route traffic thru eth0 and eth1 in FC5?

Tags: networking, routing, fedora, eth0

I have a site that uses eth0, which is a saturated gbit line, to deliver streaming media. I want to setup a separate "premium" line on eth1, to give special users "priority access" to the site. I have a 2nd 100mbit dedicated line for this.

Basically, when someone uses media.domain.com it goes thr eth0, when someone uses premium.domain.com it would use eth1

I use lighttpd

Cant figure it out....

This is what I have now, yet all traffic still goes thru eth0

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route show

61.43.52.242 dev eth1  scope link

61.43.52.128/25 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src PREMIUM_IP  metric 1

75.12.33.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src REGULAR_IP  metric 1

169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002

default via 1.3.3.7 dev eth0  proto static
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup routing to make sure that packets go back out the same interface they came in on.  This does not happen by default.

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: No cigar, didnt work.

Comment: it does work.  for someone to be able to help you, you are going to need to update your question with the changes that you made to the system after following that guide.